# Paste range of data into specific cell in newly created variable column

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm doing is running data, having it fill to a specific location, and then creating a new column at the end of the spreadsheet to show this weeks data. I have everything running smoothly, besides pasting the values into the end cell, which is going to move over by 1 column every week. I'm sure its just something simple in terms of the declaration, but I've tried paste special, and a bunch of other things to no success.

```
Sub InsertDate()

    Dim y As String
    y = "Wkly Change"
    If y = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim x As Long
    For x = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(2, x).Value = y Then
            Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
            Cells(1, x).Value = Date
            Cells(2, x).Value = "Delq"
            Cells(29, x).Value = Date
            Cells(30, x).Value = "WIP"
            'Range("B3:B27").Select
            'Selection.Copy
            'Range(3, x).Paste
            'Range("B31:B55").Select
            'Selection.Copy
            'Range(31, x).Paste
        End If
    Next x


End Sub
```

The commented out section is the part I'm having trouble with. Thanks in advance!

Comment: **[Here](http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/08/18/excel_cut_copy_paste_from_a_macro/)** is a good explanation of copy/paste.

Comment: I want it to paste into a variable range though, that's my issue. All of these have locked cell references. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I finally ended up doing to solve my problem. Not quite sure why the other solutions didnt work, but this works perfectly for what I need.

```
Sub InsertDate()

Dim y As String
y = "Wkly Change"
If y = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim x As Long
For x = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
If Cells(2, x).Value = y Then
Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Columns(x)
Cells(1, x).Value = Date
Cells(29, x).Value = Date
Columns(x).EntireColumn.AutoFit
End If
Next x


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options...

```
Range("B3:B27").Copy Destination:=Range("C3:C27") 'Notice you mixed up cells and range notation
```

or try

```
Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: My problem is that I want it to go into the newly created range, which means its going into a different column, one over to the right, every time the macro is run.

Comment: OK, but you know where the new column is (x), so set the destination to be Range(chr(64) + x & "3")

Comment: I'm getting a "Type Mismatch" error when I run this. Here's what my code looks like

Range("B3:B27").Copy Destination:=Range(Chr(64) + x & "3")

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: 3 shouldn't be in quotes - quotes implies something is a string (ie text) but it should be an integer (which doesn't need to be defined - excel will see a 3 by itself and auto assign it to the integer class)